# Easiest language to develop tcp server on ubuntu?

Tags: server, development

I would like to ask about the easiest way to develop a tcp-server on ubuntu :)

Comment: That's a VERY broad question.

Comment: Not to mention ambiguous, such as use case, etc.

Comment: I would recommend you to specify what you want, what you know, and go from there. But still it's a huge question. Have you tried to Google on the subject?

Answer (score 3):

A quick way to get a TCP server up & running is to use the [`tcpserver`](http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/tcpserver.html) program:

> NAME
>
> ```
>    tcpserver - accept incoming TCP connections
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> tcpserver  [ -146jpPhHrRoOdDqQv ] [ -climit ] [ -xrules.cdb ] 
>            [ -Bbanner ] [ -ggid ] [ -uuid ] [ -bbacklog ] [ -llocalname ] 
>            [ -ttimeout ] [ -Iinterface ] host port program [ arg ...  ]
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> `tcpserver` waits for connections from TCP clients.  For each connection, it runs program with the given arguments, with descriptor 0  reading  from the network and descriptor 1 writing to the network.
>
> The  server's  address is given by host and port.  host can be 0, allowing connections from any host; or a particular IP address, allowing connections only to that address; or a host name, allowing connections to the first IP address for that host.  port may be a numeric port  number  or  a port name.  If port is 0, `tcpserver` will choose a free port.
>
> . . .

You could also use [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/).

Comment: This is a good answer...but not to this question. While it's somewhat unclear what the OP wants here (more info will have to be provided for this question to be reopened), the OP is interesting in *writing* a TCP server (of some kind), not in what TCP relays/superservers are available out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

I would (and did) try Python with the Twisted Framework.

Comment: Twisted is quite powerful, but I wouldn't call it easiest. Especially comparing to Python's built in SocketServer http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example